# Azure ServiceBus timeout when Sending Message from Azure Web App

Tags: azure, timeout, azureservicebus

We are facing issue with web API which is hosted in Azure web app. We are inserting a message in Azure Service Bus . Getting intermittent Timeout issue when message is sent to Service Bus queue through Azure web app but when debugging the same code locally it works fine. The service bus is same in both cases. Not able to find the reason for same.Below is code snippet.

```
Logger.Log(ErrorLevel.Info, "Started Sending Message to Service Bus for Job Id :" + newjobObject.JobId);
ServiceBusRepository.SendMessageToQueue(jobEntity.JobId);
Logger.Log(ErrorLevel.Info, "Completed Sending Message to Service Bus for Job Id :" + newjobObject.JobId);
```

This is code for SendMessageToQueue method

```
public  static void SendMessageToQueue(string Message)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = new BrokeredMessage(Message);
                Logger.Log(ErrorLevel.Info,"Before SendMessagetoQueue= " + message);
                sendQueueClient.Send(message);
                Logger.Log(ErrorLevel.Info,"After SendMessagetoQueue= " + message);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

In logs only first logging statement is getting logged not the second one. So it means while sending message some exception is occurring.Anyone can provide pointers to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Intermittent timeout exceptions (`System.TimeoutException`) are transient exceptions and are acceptable. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#timeoutexception), you should add a retry logic fro any transient exception.

In addition to that, for timeout exceptions, you might want to adjust messaging factory settings (see [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#timeoutexception)).

When the client throws an exception, have a closer at that exception. It will contain info that could help. Would not hurt to post it along with the question.